# Creating an embeddable countdown timer image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, image

I am trying to create an embeddable countdown timer similar to the one seen [here](http://gen.sendtric.com/countdown/am7nv82nwt). In case that link expires, it is a countdown created from their homepage [Sendtric](http://sendtric.com). Essentially you are given a link to an image and this image can be embedded on other webpages and animates a countdown.

The code you'd use to embed it is just like any other image:

`<img src="http://gen.sendtric.com/countdown/am7nv82nwt" alt="" width="400" height="80">`

I have a website I'm working on that has similar styled timers on the website based around events that happen in a game. I want people who use the site to be able to embed these timers the same way the example I provided above does it.

It seems like they are just generating a GIF that is 1 minute in length. Essentially when the image is loaded you get an animated gif with 1 minute worth of the countdown from that point in time.

I'd like to do similar and from what I am looking at it seems like PHP doesn't work very well to create animated GIF's. Is my best bet to use PHP to generate something like 60 images (one for each second) and then use a tool like ImageMagick to make them into an animated GIF?

Or am I better off calling to code in a completely separate language from PHP to do this? Currently my site has a Laravel backend, but this specific webpage so far is all client-side (javascript, jQuery, momentJS).

Comment: Why not just do it in html/css with a script to change display?

Comment: @charlietfl That would be ideal, however I'd like to be able to have this embeddable via img tags. The specific target site only allows embedding of images into stuff like their forums. Currently I already have html/css/javascript updating the webpages counters automatically.

Comment: are you looking do to this from scratch?, i've just googled this now and there are handful of libraries that does this already in PHP.

Comment: @Kevin No I am not looking to do it from scratch. I do see libraries for stitching a series of images together. So I could generate a series of 60 images via something like PHP and then make use of a library like [AnimGif](https://github.com/lunakid/AnimGif) to stitch it together.

Comment: @ComputerLocus sure go for it and try. i haven't tried that one. just tested another one https://github.com/jamdav16/PHP-GIF-Countdown it's outdated and had to update the library to try out with your question in my local dev and it's works enough for a countdown.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Cloudinary free for generating gif along with PHP.

Comment: What kind of API calls would I use there to be able to create a gif that is say 60 seconds long worth of a countdown?